# How to get Region settings of android device programmatically?

Tags: android

I want to get region details from the android device settings to get country details. Please check attached screenshots. [region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqsYT.jpg)
Is there any way to get that value?

Please note that I have tried to get country from the device language.

```
public static String getCountryCodeByLocale() {
        String countryCode;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            countryCode = Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0).getCountry();
        } else {
            countryCode = Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().locale.getCountry();
        }

        if (countryCode != null && countryCode.length() == 2) {
            return countryCode.toLowerCase();
        }
       
        return "us";
    }
```

Please me help to get Region details of the device programmatically.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: does anyone have idea about how to achieve this?

Comment: Did you find a solution? This seems to be a vender specific option and for some reason they didn't use it as `Locale.country`. I am also facing the very same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let's check on this if it can help -

Refer the doc for more context - https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html

```
Locale defaultLocale = Locale.getDefault();
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.
I tried it as follows but it returns empty string.
`Locale loc = Locale.getDefault();  String country= loc.getCountry();`

Comment: also tried `String country= loc.getDisplayCountry();` . This also returns empty string.